# Android app crashing when control reaches findViewbyId() for recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I intended to fetch data from ConnectionClass in background and then populate it into recyclerView.

Now, I have successfully fetched the data from url in json format, but my app is crashing when I am trying to  display data using recyclerView.

Adapter Class for recyclerview

```
package com.example.mainapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.List;

import Model.PersonDetails;

public class PersonDetailsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PersonDetailsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<PersonDetails> personDetails;
    PersonDetailsAdapter(List<PersonDetails>details)
    {

        personDetails = details;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public PersonDetailsAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Log.d("create view " , personDetails.toString());
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater  inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context) ;
        View personView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.person_details_view , parent , true) ;
        ViewHolder view = new ViewHolder(personView) ;
        return view;

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        PersonDetails details = personDetails.get(position);
        holder.nameTextView.setText(details.getName());
        holder.aliasTextView.setText(details.getAlias());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return personDetails.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public TextView nameTextView;
        public TextView aliasTextView;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            nameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameHolder);
            aliasTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.aliasHolder);
        }
    }

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
 
package com.example.mainapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.example.mainapp.Utility.ConnectionClass;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.List;

import Model.PersonDetails;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button getButton  = findViewById(R.id.get);
        Button postButton  = findViewById(R.id.post);
        Context context = this.getBaseContext();
        getButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ConnectionClass conn = null;
                try {

                    conn = new ConnectionClass("URL", context);
                    conn.execute();

                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    System.out.println("connection not set ");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        postButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                          @Override
                                          public void onClick(View v) {
                                            postRequest();
                                          }
                                      }
        );



    }
    public void updateView( List<PersonDetails> personDetails ) {
        Log.d("1" , "******************************************called fro");
        RecyclerView rView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewPerson);
        Log.d("2" , "******************************************iosdjdsa");
        PersonDetailsAdapter adapter = new PersonDetailsAdapter(personDetails);
        rView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 5));
        rView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    private void postRequest() {
    }
}
```

ConnectionClass.java

```
package com.example.mainapp.Utility;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.mainapp.MainActivity;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import Model.PersonDetails;
public class ConnectionClass extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>  {
    private URL url ;
    private HttpURLConnection conn;
    private String  response ;
    private Context context ;

    public ConnectionClass() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        Log.d("onPost", "*****************************************postexe");
        Toast.makeText(context, "Records fetched",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        List<PersonDetails> details = new ArrayList<>();
        try {

            JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(response);
            for( int i = 0; i < arr.length() ; ++i )
            {
                JSONObject jObject = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                PersonDetails record = new PersonDetails(jObject.getString("name"),jObject.getString("alias") );
                details.add(record);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d("t","json exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d( "detalis", "**************************************"+details.toString());
        MainActivity activity = new MainActivity();
        activity.updateView(details);
    }

    public ConnectionClass(String url, Context context) throws MalformedURLException {
        this.url = new URL (url);
        conn = null ;
        this.context = context;
    }
//    public void sendRequest(){
//        try {
//            System.out.println("\n\n***************************************hello**********************\n\n");
//            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
//            conn.setDoOutput(false);
//            conn.setDoInput(true);
//            conn.setUseCaches(false);
//            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
//            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
//            conn.connect();
//            // handle the response
//            System.out.println("\n\n***************************************here**********************\n\n");
//
//            int status = conn.getResponseCode();
//            System.out.println(status);
//
//            if (status != 200)
//                throw new IOException("Request not completed");
//            else
//            {
//                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
//                String inputLine ;
//                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder() ;
//                while((inputLine = in.readLine())  != null )
//                    builder.append(inputLine);
//                in.close();
//                response = builder.toString();
//            }
//
//        }
//        catch (IOException e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }
//        finally{
//            if( conn != null )
//                conn.disconnect();
//        }
//    }
    public void setUrl(String url) throws MalformedURLException {
        this.url = new URL(url);
    }
    public String getResponse() {
        return response;
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        try {
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            Log.d("conn", "***************************************************************************connectioon set " ) ;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);

        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        try {
            conn.connect();
            Log.d("conn " , "**********************************************************************connected ");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        BufferedReader br = null;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try{
         br =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        char[] buffer = new char[1024];
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line+"\n");
        }
        Log.d("sb" , String.valueOf(sb));
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            Log.d("finally ", "*****************************************************************************************finally");
            response = sb.toString();
            System.out.println("JSON: " + response);
            conn.disconnect();
        }




        return null ;

    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="-3dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nameText"
                android:layout_width="141dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/aliasText"
                android:layout_width="141dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="119dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nameText" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/post"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-11dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:text="POST" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/get"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:text="GET" />

        </RelativeLayout>
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerViewPerson"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#972A2A" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

xml for RecyclerView content

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="50dp"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameHolder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/aliasHolder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Application is crashing when control reaches updateView()?

Comment: `AsyncTask` is deprecated by the way. It's hard to use anyways. If you are writing this today, you might want to try Kotlin coroutines.

Answer (score 0):

`MainActivity activity = new MainActivity();`

You cannot just create the instance using the constructor. You should pass a reference of MainActivity to make it work. You need just to change a few lines of the code: 
In `ConnectionClass` replace field `private Context context;` by `private MainActivity activity;` and change the constructor accordingly:

```
public ConnectionClass(String url, MainActivity activity) throws MalformedURLException {
    this.url = new URL (url);
    conn = null ;
    this.activity = activity;
}
```

After that, you will be able to call `activity.updateView(details);`.

And don't forget to remove `MainActivity activity = new MainActivity();`

Further reading: 
[Proper use of AsyncTask](https://medium.com/@akashdee/good-async-task-hunting-async-template-with-best-practices-used-within-the-activity-or-as-a-41830bdbfb2f) 
[AsyncTask deprecation and alternatives](https://medium.com/swlh/asynctask-is-deprecated-now-what-f30c31362761)

Comment: Can you please  elaborate, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Add your AsyncTask code at the bottom of your MainActivity and then update the recyclerview like this:

`updateView(details);`

Answer (score 0):

```
    MainActivity activity = new MainActivity();
    activity.updateView(details);
```

You can't instantiate activity like this; if you want to call a method in the activity within the AsynkTask class `ConnectionClass`; you can pass a listener to it and implement this listener in the activity, and then invoke the callback of that listener when you want to call some functionality in the activity.

```
interface ConnectionClassListener {
    void onPostExecuteFinished(List<PersonDetails> personDetails);
}
```

Pass the class to the AsyncTask constructor

```
public class ConnectionClass extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>  {

    ConnectionClassListener mConnectionClassListener;
    public ConnectionClass(String url, Context context, ConnectionClassListener listener) throws MalformedURLException {
        this.url = new URL (url);
        conn = null ;
        this.context = context;
        mConnectionClassListener = listener;
    }
```

Implement the listener by the activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ConnectionClassListener {
    @Override
    void onPostExecuteFinished(List<PersonDetails> personDetails) {
            //  Do here what you want when the ConnectionClass calls `onPostExecuteFinished()`

            updateView(personDetails);
    }
}
```

add `this` when creating the AsynkTask class

```
conn = new ConnectionClass("URL", context, this);
```

And finally call `onPostExecuteFinished()` in your `ConnectionClass`

```
public class ConnectionClass extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>  {
    // ...

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        //        ...
        mConnectionClassListener.onPostExecuteFinished(details);
```

Comment: **Of course it would not work** when between `execute` call and `onPostExecute` user rotate the screen

Answer (score 0):

Let me clarify @sdex answer:

When you create an instance of `Activity` - in your case `MainActivity` - it doesn't have a view, it is not visible to the user and it's not added to the Activity stack. You could say - this activity is "Dead"

In order to display the result to your currently running `MainActivity`, so it's displayed to the user, you need to pass the instance of it to the `ConnectionClass` class. For example - pass it to the **constructor** of the ConnectionClass.

By the way - please consider **moving away** from `AsyncTask`, it's been deprecated and could be a reason for the `Context` leaks, meaning - you'll have massive objects, that are no more visible to the user are retaining in the memory.

In order to avoid leaking the Activity reference, please store it as the "WeakReference"